# Validar dados de registo (spring-boot + angularjs)

Tags: java, aplicação-web, spring, rest, spring-boot

Olá,

Estou a implementar um projecto web em spring boot + data + angularjs. Em que o cliente faz pedidos rest ao servidor. Do lado do Spring estou a usar repositórios para desenvolver a pesquisa a base de dados com CrudRepository.

```
@RepositoryRestResource
public interface ClientRepository  extends CrudRepository< Client , Integer > { 

    List< Client > findAll( );

}
```

Só que preciso para editar a função save do repositório. Tentei criar uma camada de serviços que executa-se o save mas não está a funcionar.

```
@Component( "clientService" )
@Transactional
public class ClientRepositoryImpl implements ClientService{

    private final ClientRepository clientRepository;

    public ClientRepositoryImpl( ClientRepository clientRepository ) {
        this.clientRepository = clientRepository;
    }


    @Override
    public String addClient( Client saved ) {
            // ....
            if( this.clientRepository.save( saved ) != null )
                return "OK";
            else 
                return "NOK";

    }  

}
```

Alguém consegue dar uma ideia como posso criar alguma lógica antes de invocar o save do repositório ?
Estou a fazer o registo preciso de validar os dados inseridos no lado do servidor e não sei bem como validar antes do repositório fazer save. Já que no lado do cliente faço uma chamada rest ( /clients ) com os parâmetros para inserir.

Answer (score 1):

Não costumo usar o spring-data-rest, pois a abordagem dele é um pouco diferente da qual eu estou acostumado a usar. Prefiro usar spring-hateoas e desenvolver os rest controllers por minha conta, isso torna possível usar vários outros recursos que o ecosistema spring possui.

Mas como você está utilizando essa abordagem e eu gostaria de te ajudar, sugiro que você crie um bean de Validator para a sua entidade e registre ele ao evento BeforeCreate.

Exemplo:

```
@Component
class BeforeCreatePersonValidator implements Validator {

    public boolean supports(Class clazz) {
        return Person.class.equals(clazz);
    }

    public void validate(Object obj, Errors e) {
        ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmpty(e, "name", "name.empty");
        Person p = (Person) obj;
        if (p.getAge() < 0) {
            e.rejectValue("age", "negativevalue");
        } else if (p.getAge() > 110) {
            e.rejectValue("age", "too.darn.old");
        }
    }
}
```

Apenas essa classe nomeada como BeforeCreatePersonValidator e anotada com @Component já deve ser o suficiente para validar uma entidade chamada Pessoa, antes que ela seja persistida ao banco de dados, de acordo com a [documentação](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/2.5.3.RELEASE/reference/html/#validation).

Se você quiser ter mais alguma idéia sobre validação de dados do cliente, você pode olhar na [documentação do spring-framework](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#validator).

Espero ter ajudado.